# react-map-gl: Map Does Not Appear

Tags: javascript, mapbox, reactjs, mapbox-gl-js

I'm using the [react-map-gl](https://github.com/uber/react-map-gl) package from Uber, but even after trying it for a few days, haven't been able to get it to work.

I'm not trying to do anything fancy (yet) - for now, I simply want a map to appear on my page. I figured that once I got that step to work, I can try more advanced things.

Unfortunately, this is all I see:

[image: Map Image]

Any suggestions?

Here's the relevant section of my code (from the .jsx file):

```jsx
import React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import MapGL from 'react-map-gl'

const App = React.createClass({

  render: function () {
    const map = (
        <div>
          <MapGL
            width={700}
            height={450}
            latitude={37.78}
            longitude={-122.45}
            zoom={11}
            mapStyle={'mapbox://styles/mapbox/basic-v9'}
            mapboxApiAccessToken={'pk.ey...<removed for privacy>...'}
          />
        </div>
      )

    return (
      <div>
        =======Map should be below=======
        <br/>
        { map }
        <br/>
        =======Map should be above=======
      </div>
    )
  }
})

export default connect()(App)
```

Everything else on my site works; the only thing missing is that the map does not actually appear.
Thanks in advance for any help provided.

Comment: Do you see any errors in your console?

Comment: @LucasWojciechowski - I do have a "React attempted to reuse markup in a container but the checksum was invalid.." warning but I'm reasonably certain that's from a different area of the code, since that appears even when I replace the <MapGL /> element with a simple <div>Hello!</div> element. Otherwise no errors.

Comment: Can you post a runnable example of your broken code? It is hard for me to debug with the information provided.

Comment: I have no problem running the exact same code so I don't think that's the problem. Are you using Webpack ? Any warning or error on this end ?

Comment: @HiDeo Based on how few other people have this problem, I'm starting to wonder if perhaps I have an outdated module or something similar. That said, I'd feel a lot better if I had a working example written in React's .jsx notation which I knew worked for someone else, as I could use that example as a way to check if my modules are outdated. If you (or someone else) writes such an example and verify it works, I'll give you (or someone else) the bounty!

Comment: I have added an answer containing a simple walkthrough to get your exact same JSX code tested and working, the result is the correct map displayed by react-map-gl.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As per your request in the comments, I've put up a simple walkthrough to test your code.

I've chosen a random react boilerplate to save some time. I clone it and install all its dependencies.

```
git clone https://github.com/coryhouse/react-slingshot
cd react-slingshot
npm install
```

Then, I install [react-map-gl](https://github.com/uber/react-map-gl).

```
npm install react-map-gl --save
```

We now need to install some dependencies required for [react-map-gl](https://github.com/uber/react-map-gl) to work correctly.

```
npm install json-loader transform-loader webworkify-webpack@1.0.6 --save-dev
```

The only specific here is the v1.0.6 of webworkify-webpack which is to my knowledge the last version compatible out of the box with [react-map-gl](https://github.com/uber/react-map-gl).

Next, we need add proper configuration directives to Webpack in the `webpack.config.dev.js` file for example.

First, we add a `resolve` block

```
resolve: {
  extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx'],
  alias: {
    webworkify: 'webworkify-webpack',
  }
},
```

And we simply add the loaders we need to the existing ones.

```
/** ... Previous loaders ... **/
{test: /\.json$/, loader: 'json-loader'},
{test: /\.js$/, include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/webworkify/index.js'), loader: 'worker'},
{test: /mapbox-gl.+\.js$/, loader: 'transform/cacheable?brfs'},
```

The last step is to simply put your code in a component to got it displayed (`src/components/HomePage.js`).

```
import MapGL from 'react-map-gl';

/** ... **/

return (
  <div>
    <MapGL
      width={700}
      height={450}
      latitude={37.78}
      longitude={-122.45}
      zoom={11}
      mapboxApiAccessToken={'pk.eyJ1IjoiMW0yMno1Nmw3N2sifQ.YNkaLBJBc4lNXa5A'}
      mapStyle={'mapbox://styles/mapbox/basic-v9'}
    />
  </div>
);
```

To test the app, we use

```
npm start
```

A browser will open with the following content. It's the [JSX](https://facebook.github.io/jsx/) code you provided, the only modification is my Mapbox API access token.

[image: The map works.]

My wild guess would be that you have some problem with the way you're bundling your app, either with [Webpack](https://webpack.github.io/) or another bundler.

Comment: you turned out to be right, I had a line `devtool: 'eval'` in my webpack config that was causing issues.

Answer (score 3):

The symptom of no visible map *smells* like an API access token issue.

The [Readme.md](https://github.com/uber/react-map-gl#development) describes a bash command to check your access token.

```
echo $MapboxAccessToken
npm start &
open "http://localhost:9966/?access_token=$MapboxAccessToken"
```

The [Github source](https://github.com/uber/react-map-gl/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=mapboxApiAccessToken) makes use of `mapboxApiAccessToken`, but the [test sample](https://github.com/uber/react-map-gl/blob/5a7065e7d46b1e5a503c35afe266cb7261a2853f/test/index.js#L24) show the usage slightly different than what you posted, using `r()`.

```
  var map = r(MapGL, {
    width: 500,
    height: 500,
    longitude: -122,
    latitude: 37,
    zoom: 14,
    mapboxApiAccessToken: mapboxApiAccessToken
  });
  React.render(map, document.body);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I've used the bash command to verify that my mapbox access token is working correctly. So unfortunately, I don't think that's the issue.

Comment: I saw the test sample as well, but wasn't quite sure how to adapt it to the .jsx notation

Answer (score 0):

Well, this worked when I ejected the app